# Muitas questões votadas para serem fechadas

Tags: debate

Me deparei com um número grande de questões sendo votadas para serem fechada hoje a noite.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como não tinha ninguém no chat resolvi perguntar aqui o que está acontecendo...

Comment: Quando eu cheguei estava em 36.

Comment: Pelo que vi eram questões antigas e abandonadas, tipicas perguntas vagas que alguém pede mais informação e o AP some.

Comment: Agora que vi meu avatar no print :)

Comment: Eu ia votar pra fechar aqui pois não tinha visto pergunta, mas a resposta do bigown me fez entender do que se trata.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O Papa Charlie acertou. Todas as perguntas eram antigas, sem resposta e tinham problemas. A maioria não estava clara, faltava informações muitas vezes que foram pedidas e estava evidente que a pergunta tinha sido abandonada pelo AP. Mais ainda, na maioria elas são sobre problemas muito específicos que não vai ajudar mais ninguém além do usuário que desapareceu.

Elas podem ser reabertas um dia mas provavelmente não serão. Ainda faltam mais algumas poucas que preciso por na fila. Agradeço todos que ajudaram.

Algumas saíram da fila porque algumas pessoas acharam que devia permanecer aberta. Cada um tem sua opinião e eu achei que iria acontecer com algumas, mas eu errei as que iriam acontecer. Tem pergunta que teve mais votos para deixar aberta que é completo *dead end*. Não tem o que fazer ali. Pelo conteúdo eu acho que nestes casos preferiram deixar aberta pelo gosto pelo assunto e não analisaram a qualidade da pergunta específica. Se me lembro bem acho que concordei apenas com uma que eu mesmo achei que não era tão problemática.

Tem várias perguntas que não votei para fechar porque não há um problema mais sério. Precisaremos em algum momento decidir o que fazer com perguntas antigas abandonadas (AP fugiu, não teve resposta) e a pergunta é muito específica, não vai ajudar ninguém, nem mesmo quem perguntou que não voltará para ver se tiver um resultado no futuro. Eu particularmente acho que elas deverão em algum momento ser fechadas como *Não reproduzível*, por falta de um motivo melhor (que existia no passado).

Eu tenho tentado resolver algumas coisas que ficaram largadas. Vocês ficaram sabendo das mais visíveis, nem tudo é tão aparente. Não sabem que estou tentando e ainda vou tentar mais dar uma agitada em perguntas que ainda podem ter alguma solução, mesmo que a chance seja pequena.

#### Eventualmente tenho fechado mais algumas perguntas esporádicas. Seria interessante a leitura dos comentários para acompanhar o que está acontecendo e entender os motivos que me levaram a iniciar o fechamento, concordando ou não.

Comment: Acho muito bem bigown, tenho pena de não ter podido ajudar, mas sempre que puder ajudo. Grande iniciativa que deve ser louvada!

Comment: A solução para perguntas antigas abandonadas é essa mesmo, fazer um "faxinão" de tempos em tempos. Vale lembrar que o próprio sistema também se encarrega de excluir perguntas esquecidas que atendam a [determinados critérios](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1558/74).

Comment: Confesso que só fui reparar na data depois de umas 5 analisadas, até então achei que estavam "em dia", só depois reparei que eram antigas e passei a dar mais atenção e ver como abandonadas.

Comment: Por isso é bom analisar a pergunta como um todo antes de tomar qualquer decisão. Eu sei que tem gente que sequer vê o que aparece na fila de análise. Eu abro a página em outra aba para ver o *big picture* do problema e ter melhores subsídios para votar. Espero que esta dicar sirva para ajudar a todos melhorarem seus votos. Eu ainda erro assim mesmo, mas aí não foi falha no processo de análise e sim na decisão.