# O que fazer com perguntas antigas abandonadas?

Tags: debate, perguntas, perguntas-sem-resposta

Em primeiro lugar quero dizer que realmente não sei, não estou sugerindo nada, espero que você possa sugerir.

Eu tenho procurando perguntas antigas que parecem que não vão a lugar algum. [Tenho iniciado o processo de votação em alguns casos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2134/101). São casos que me pareceram óbvios que precisavam de fechamento. Quase todos teve concordância de outras pessoas.

Mas há casos não tão óbvios do que fazer. São perguntas antigas que foram abandonadas pelo AP (não voltou mais ao site), sem respostas válidas e que se um dia venha ter uma resposta, muito provavelmente irá beneficiar só o AP mesmo, que não saberá dela. Claro, estou falando de probabilidades. Estou falando de julgar caso a caso como sempre fazemos em todas as análises que podemos fazer no site. Não falo de fazer nada roboticamente.

O que fazer nestes casos?

- Nada

  Ou fazer um comentário, uma edição para ativar a pergunta na página principal. É uma opção perfeitamente válida, se isto for feito não vejo necessariamente que gere problemas fundamentais para o site. Pode gerar um efeito positivo temporário e resolver a questão definitivamente. Mas pode continuar como está.
- Fechar

  Qual motivo? Estou falando de casos que não existem motivos tão óbvios. Antes talvez existisse algo mais próximo que era o "muito localizado", agora talvez seja o "não reproduzível" já que ninguém conseguiu fazer alguma coisa. Não estou dizendo que este é o melhor motivo. Quero saber se vocês acham que seria correto usar este expediente para finalizar a pergunta. Se for para usar outro motivo, por quê?
- Negativar

  Se considerarmos que a pergunta não está sendo muito útil para ninguém, *rankear* a pergunta de forma que ela fique com votação de pelo menos -1 pode esperar melhor as perguntas. O voto negativo serve para classificar o que não é útil. Mas isto seria válido neste caso?
- Outro

  Especifique.

Gostaria de ver a opinião de vários usuários para ter um parâmetro da opinião geral. Se tem outras justificativas para cada ação, quero saber. Ajude dar parâmetros para saber o que fazer que agrade a comunidade.

Alguns exemplos do que estou falando (peguei os primeiros que achei, não são necessariamente os mais descritivos da questão):

[Erro numa Trigger envolvendo Linked Server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/18898/erro-numa-trigger-envolvendo-linked-server)

[Adicionar efeito carrossel (loop infinito) a um slider pronto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9330/adicionar-efeito-carrossel-loop-infinito-a-um-slider-pronto)

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10528/como-eu-faria-em-um-wpf-para-apontar-para-para-uma-atualiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-um-servidor

[Como converter endereço em coordenadas no Windows Phone?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17636/como-converter-endere%C3%A7o-em-coordenadas-no-windows-phone)

[Erro numa Trigger envolvendo Linked Server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/18898/erro-numa-trigger-envolvendo-linked-server)

[Layout MessageBox WPF](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/18966/layout-messagebox-wpf)

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13428/download-arquivo-blob-php-mysql

Coloquei as últimas com respostas mas que ninguém validou para mostrar situações diferentes que encontrei.

Comment: Qual search query vc tá usando para localizar essas candidatas? Me pergunto também quais dessas iniciativas atrapalham a limpeza automática...

Comment: Cada hora escolho alguma coisa diferente mas na maior parte do tempo eu vou na aba de `Sem resposta` da página de `Perguntas` ou vou na página de `Sem Resposta` que tem critério diferente. A primeira opção, se fizer uma edição pode atrasar uma remoção, isso pode ser considerado bom ou ruim. As duas seguintes podem ajudar ou não mudar nada para facilitar uma remoção em alguns casos, mas não pode ajudar a não ser removida por si só. Claro que sempre é possível existir efeitos colaterais. Você pode por na fila de fechamento e alguém editar, ou responder (que seria algo positivo).

Answer (score 10):

Na minha opinião, o ideal seria se existisse uma funcionalidade de **ignorar perguntas**. Explico:

1. Se não fizermos nada, essas perguntas continuarão ocupando espaço nas abas de "sem resposta". Eu já tentei algumas vezes (no SOen) visitar essa aba à procura de perguntas que eu soubesse responder, mas não só nunca encontrei nada como cansei de ficar encontrando sempre as mesmas perguntas lá.
2. Se fecharmos ou negativarmos, dificultamos para que *outras pessoas* a encontrem - o fato de que todo mundo que já viu uma pergunta não soube responder não significa que ninguém mais sabe. Além disso, se outras pessoas tiverem o mesmo problema é melhor que elas simplesmente votem positivo numa pergunta já existente (mostrando que ela permanece relevante, e que uma resposta pra mesma é bastante desejável) do que criem uma duplicata.

Em outras palavras, por mais que eu queira que as perguntas que eu já vi e não soube responder (e também não me interessam pessoalmente) desapareçam *pra mim*, eu não considero interessante que elas desapareçam *pro resto da comunidade*.

Ignorar certas tags ajudam, mas não resolvem - ou eu configuro minhas preferências para esconder perguntas nas tags ignoradas *pra todo o site* ou não (não dá pra fazer isso só naquelas abas em particular). Além disso, pode ter perguntas que não me interessam nas minhas tags favoritas também. *Talvez* num site "pequeno" como o SOpt esse problema seja gerenciável, mas duvido que o mesmo ocorra no SOen por exemplo.

P.S. Na ausência disso, minha ação sugerida por ora é "não fazer nada".

Comment: Eu também acho que ignorar perguntas de verdade por critérios do usuário deveria ser um recurso básico do site mas a SE não vai mudar isto enquanto perdurar a mentalidade que antes da UX vem depois da necessidade de manter o processador dos servidores operando c/ 2% da capacidade.

Comment: _"cansei de ficar encontrando sempre as mesmas perguntas lá."_ Não seria esse um motivo de marcar as perguntas como duplicadas em vez de simplesmente ignorá-las?

Comment: @EMBarbosa Duplicatas do quê? Podem ser perguntas únicas, canônicas até, só que em aberto... (quando eu disse "as mesmas perguntas" eu quis dizer literalmente - ver a mesma pergunta várias vezes - e não várias perguntas iguais ou parecidas)

Comment: Ah, agora sim faz sentido o que disse. Mas daí então realmente não há o que se pode fazer. Exceto ordenar as perguntas por data e com o tempo elas caírem numa espécie de "limbo".

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro lugar, gostaria de deixar claro, como você mesmo disse em sua pergunta que isso não é generalizado. Mas sim julgar caso a caso. Fora isso, minha opinião é:

**"Nada".**

Até onde sei, (é o que eu sigo pra mim), deve-se usar o comentar sempre que for preciso, o negativar sem comentar moderadamente, o fechar quando for absolutamente necessário.

Se você não puder/quiser fazer isso, então é melhor não fazer nada.

Por exemplo: Eu tenho uma pergunta que foi marcada para deleção, sem votos negativos ou positivos, sem visualizações. Nem ao menos fui avisado que ela seria apagada. Ela ser apagada não me adiciona nada. Não foi me dado motivos, o porquê a pergunta não era boa. Eu não cresci de forma alguma. Vou continuar a fazer perguntas iguais, ou pior, vou ignorar o SO, ou pior, vou continuar a fazer perguntas iguais, ou pior, vou ignorar o SO. (Tudo bem, não sei o que é pior...)